# Scaling the reassignment of levels across different factors

Tags: r

I regularly work with survey data to derive sentiment scores from people's responses. Some questions are not required fields, and therefore contain blanks while others they may choose to exclude themselves from the answer by putting things like, "Not Applicable." A final challenge is that the (standardized) options given to people *across* questions may not always be the same. However, the blanks and, "Not Applicable", values typically are. When importing this dataset, the advantage of creating these various questions into factors is that I'll eventually encode them into a numeric equivalent - and can therefore apply different visualization and statistical methods over the data.

A downside to this is that I have not found a way to scale the remapping of these uniform levels across factors (with different levels amongst them).

```
age_group <- c("10-20 years old", "21-30 years old", "10-20 years old", "") # natural order to this 
favorite_color <- c("blue", "red", "green", "") # a vector without an ordinal set of levels
education <- c("primary", "secondary", "primary", "")

df_info <- data.frame(factor(age_group, levels = c( "", "10-20 years old", "21-30 years old")),
                      factor(favorite_color, levels = c("", "red", "green", "blue")),
                      factor(education, levels = c("", "primary", "secondary")))
names(df_info) <- c("Age", "Color", "Edu")
```

Given the above, I identified that the following methods work:

```
levels(df_info$Color)[1] <- 'missing'
levels(df_info$Edu)[1] <- 'missing'
levels(df_info$Age)[1] <- 'missing'
```

Similarly, the following also works:

```
levels(df_info[paste('Color')])[1] <- 'missing'
# ...etc.
```

However, when trying to scale this and calling the "levels" function to validate that this method has worked, I return NULL. **WHY???**

```
# This DOES NOT work:
change_list <- c("Age", "Color", "Edu")
for( item in change_list ) {
   levels(df_info[paste(item)])[1] <- 'missing'
}

# Result of levels(df_info$*AnyVariable*) is **NULL**
```

Fortunately, I'm not *yet* working on large enough scale where a manual solution isn't possible, but it irks me that there isn't a more effective method to remove these blanks from the factors. All help and commentary greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `forcats` package that is part of the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df_info %>% mutate_if(is.factor, funs(fct_recode(., missing = ""))

              Age   Color       Edu
1 10-20 years old    blue   primary
2 21-30 years old     red secondary
3 10-20 years old   green   primary
4         missing missing   missing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `[` to `[[`, the former returns a single column data frame while the latter returns the column vector:

```
class(df_info['Age'])
# [1] "data.frame"
class(df_info[['Age']])
# [1] "factor"
```

Runs:

```
lapply(df_info, levels)
#$Age
#[1] ""                "10-20 years old" "21-30 years old"

#$Color
#[1] ""      "red"   "green" "blue" 

#$Edu
#[1] ""          "primary"   "secondary"

change_list <- c("Age", "Color", "Edu")
for( item in change_list ) {
   levels(df_info[[item]])[1] <- 'missing'
#                ^^    ^^ 
}

lapply(df_info, levels)
#$Age
#[1] "missing"         "10-20 years old" "21-30 years old"

#$Color
#[1] "missing" "red"     "green"   "blue"   

#$Edu
#[1] "missing"   "primary"   "secondary"
```